# I wanted to install debian 10, but before that i would like to get a live session

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I downloaded a debian-live. Unfortunately when I boot from the installation media I don't find any option to try it. All I see is options to install and graphical install. My ubuntu just works fine with settings UEFI and secure boot on.

Comment: You either just don't see it, or you're using something else. Live install is of course available in Debian https://www.debian.org/CD/live/

Comment: Have you tried boot it with Legacy Boot option instead of UEFI?

Comment: Thanks for coming back and providing an answer!  If you like, you can also mark the question as resolved by clicking the grey tick on the left of your own answer.  The tick will turn green.  This will also be noticable in the list of questions / when your question appears in search.  We will (I expect) additionally mark this question closed.  The question as written requires further information that it does not contain. So we don't need to allow other people posting alternative answers to what you already posted.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved..! actually its the startup disk creator which is failing to select desired source disc image, it kept on selecting the previous one debian net install image which I've tried earlier and that's not changing when I'm trying to change different disc image, so I've created bootable USB with Disks app. Its working now gng to try and install Debian

Comment: To clarify your answer - you are using the Startup Disk Creator provided by Ubuntu, right? If I remember correctly, this app has to recognize the disk image in some way. For example, I think it also refuses to accept Fedora Linux disk images.

Comment: yeah, the same thing happened with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the page hard to navigate: if I click what seems like the correct thing it takes me to a page of torrent files for the non-live installer.

Check the file-name.

The correct ones are in https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/ (You may need to change the architecture: You did not say)